# Who is known before : Asymptotic expansion or factorial notion?

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, factorial, math-history

My question here is trivial , just I want to know who was dicsovred before than other : [Asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) or [factorial notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say factorial because that was known to Diophantus and mathematicians in India, China, and other places long before the idea of asymptotic expansions came about.